# What is the default parameter in kernel function in package e1071 in R

Tags: r

I try to understand the kernel function. I want to know what is the default parameter of kernel function in R package e1071. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter ?svm you get the output below (-> radial).

```
## S3 method for class 'formula'
svm(formula, data = NULL, ..., subset, na.action =
na.omit, scale = TRUE)
## Default S3 method:
svm(x, y = NULL, scale = TRUE, type = NULL, kernel =
"radial", degree = 3, gamma = if (is.vector(x)) 1 else 1 / ncol(x),
coef0 = 0, cost = 1, nu = 0.5,
class.weights = NULL, cachesize = 40, tolerance = 0.001, epsilon = 0.1,
shrinking = TRUE, cross = 0, probability = FALSE, fitted = TRUE,
..., subset, na.action = na.omit)
```